# Sacrifice create before it gets destroyed

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Let's say, I have played [Altar of Dementia](http://magiccards.info/tp/en/266.html) (some rounds ago), which allows me to sacrifice a creature (at any time) to force a player to put a number of cards from the top of his or her library into his or her graveyard. Now an opponent casts [Terror](http://magiccards.info/dpa/en/34.html) (or any similar card) to destroy one of my creatures.

My question: Is it possible to sacrifice my creature before Terror applies to force the opponent to put the accordant amount of cards in his or her graveyard (in respone of Terror)?

Comment: Although the question "Can the “Sacrifice (this card):” activated ability be placed back on the stack?" might look different from your question, its answers go into the details of when you can place hings on the stack and how to respond to that. Your answer is there.

Comment: Thx for your response. I had some trouble to understand the answer from the linked question, but now I do understand. Btw: How do I proceed with this/my duplicate (leave it or delete it)? Just want to do things right :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes... You sac your creature in response to your opponent casting the spell to destroy your creature.